# Computing lg(N!): Anyone have a Better Recursive Method?

Tags: c++, recursion, factorial, logarithm

I think the title of the post addresses my question. But just to reiterate, I am wondering if anyone has a better approach to this problem.

```
/* Write a recursive program to compute lg( N! ) */

#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

long double log_base2( long double N ) {
    return log( N )/log( 2.0 );
}

long double lg_n_factorial( long N ) {
    if( 1 == N ) return log_base2( static_cast<long double>( N ) );
    else return lg_n_factorial( N -1 ) + log_base2( static_cast<long double>( N ) );
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    cout << ( lg_n_factorial( 10 ) ) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Based on people's responses, I should clarify, this is a problem out of a book, and the book says to do it recursivly. I am practicing programming problems, and trying to get feedback from others so I can catch my mistakes as I work on becoming a better programmer.

Comment: Is argument to `lg_n_factorial()` always a constant value ?

Comment: There's no need for the static_casts, compiler will convert from long to long double autmatically.

Comment: A different approach, stricly as a learning exercise, would be to write a tail recursive solution, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Tail-recursive_functions

Comment: For an even faster solution, you could take the Taylor series for ln(x) (there is a variant which is valid for all x > 1) and use that to calculate log_2(x!) as a sum of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it iteratively? I don't see a reason this problem needs to be solved recursively. If you have a requirement (For some reason or other) to do it recursively your way appears to work fine, although your base case can just be to return 0 (log(1) in any base is 0).

Also, there's no need to convert to base 2 at each step: You can do it once at the end.

Comment: Doing it once at the end will result in overflow much earlier, probably for any `N` greater than or equal to 12.  His version will handle any value for which `lg(N!) < LDBL_MAX`, which is considerably higher.

Comment: @James: no it won't. Mark B says "don't convert to base 2 at each step". In other words, move `/log(2.0)` to the end. There is no overflow in `log(12) + ... + log(1)`.

Comment: @Steve Aha! He meant converting the logrithm to base 2.  I misunderstood, and though he meant taking the base 2 logrithm.  (I don't know why.  Once I realize what was meant, it seems clear enough.)

Answer (score 3):

Why do it using recursion?  An iterative solution works just as well:

```
long double lg_n_factorial( long N ) {
    long double result = 0;
    while (N > 1) {
        result += log_base2(static_cast<long double>(N));
        N--;
    } 
    return result;
}
```

This way the maximum value you can process is only constrained by the value of `LONG_MAX`, instead of by how many recursive calls happen to fit on your stack before it overflows.

Comment: This question is probably relevant here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394174/how-best-to-sum-up-lots-of-floating-point-numbers

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you got the basic idea correctly.  From a stylistic point
of view, the code would be more readable if you had a single return
statement, and used `?:`, but for such short programs, the difference is
negligible, and not worth worrying about.  And more of a personal taste,
I'd put the recursion at the very end, to make it very clear that it is
tail recursion.  (And compiler detecting tail recursion should be able
to reorder the arithmetic and find it, but human readers see it clearer
if the recursion is the very last thing.)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's an addition involving the result of the recursive call, so it's not tail recursive.

Comment: @molbdnilo Good point.  No matter how you write it, the code has to recurse before it does the addition, so the compiler can't do tail recursion elimination.

Comment: I wonder if there is any C compiler smart enough to introduce an additional accumulator parameter in order to transform to a tail-recursive function. To do it the obvious way it would also need permission to assume that `double` addition is associative and commutative.