# How best to change floating point numbers in a list while keeping ratios?

Tags: language-agnostic, floating-accuracy, numerical-analysis

I am writing a JVM-hosted application that deals with many floating point numbers; for this reason, the program faces severe precision loss problems. Real values are a no-no as performance is an issue, too.

Given a collection of positive doubles (length can be any above 100 and below 100,000) I need to change each element accordingly to a parameter *p*, with two fundamental requirements:

1. The sum of all values must be equal to *p*.
2. Ratios should remain equal, or change as little as possible.

A very simple example with *n=3* and *p=10.0*: `(0.45, 2.0, 0.05)` becomes `(1.8, 8.0, 0.2)`.

**Is there any library to achieve this result? If not, what algorithm should I use?**

Comment: Multiply each element in the list L by `p/SUM(L)`?

Comment: That won't work for values without an exact `double` representation. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394174/how-best-to-sum-up-lots-of-floating-point-numbers) question.

Comment: @FilippoC. Nothing will work for values without an exact `double` representation. It remains the correct answer.