# Sum of array of floats returns different results

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

Here I have a function `sum()` of type `float` that takes in a pointer `t` of type `float` and an integer `size`. It returns the sum of all the elements in the array. Then I create two arrays using that function. One that has the BIG value at the first index and one that has it at the last index. When I return the sums of each of those arrays I get different results. 
**This is my code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N     1024
#define SMALL 1.0
#define BIG   100000000.0

float sum(float* t, int size) {        // here I define the function sum()
  float s = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    s += t[i];
  }
  return s;
}

int main() {
  float tab[N];
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    tab[i] = SMALL;
  }

  tab[0] = BIG;
  float sum1 = sum(tab, N);            // initialize sum1 with the big value at index 0
  printf("sum1 = %f\n", sum1);

  tab[0] = SMALL;
  tab[N-1] = BIG;
  float sum2 = sum(tab, N);            // initialize sum2 with the big value at last index
  printf("sum2 = %f\n", sum2);

  return 0;
}
```

**After compiling the code and running it I get the following output:**

```
Sum = 100000000.000000
Sum = 100001024.000000
```

**Why** do I get different results even though the arrays have the same elements ( but at different indexes ).

Comment: Do not use float, as this data type has very limited precision. Use double.

Comment: IMO [How best to sum up lots of floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394174/how-best-to-sum-up-lots-of-floating-point-numbers) is a bad choice for a duplicate.  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) is probably closer as it at least attempts to explain **why**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is [floating point imprecision](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Floating-point_arithmetic#/Accuracy_problems). Here's a simple demonstration.

```
int main() {
    float big = 100000000.0;
    float small = 1.0;

    printf("%f\n", big + small);

    printf("%f\n", big + (19 *small));

    return 0;
}
```

You'd expect 100000001.0 and 100000019.0.

```
$ ./test
100000000.000000
100000016.000000
```

Why'd that happen? Because computers don't store numbers like we do, [floating point numbers doubly so](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Floating-point_arithmetic#/IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers). A `float` has a size of just 32 bits, but can store numbers up to about 3^38 rather than the just 2^31 a 32 bit integer can. And it can store decimal places. How? They cheat. What it really stores is the sign, an exponent, and a mantissa.

```
sign * 2^exponent * mantissa
```

The mantissa is what determines accuracy and there's only 24 bits in a `float`. So large numbers lose precision.

You can [read about exactly how](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [play around with the representation](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

To solve this either use a `double` which has greater precision, or use an accurate, but slower, [arbitrary precision library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) such as GMP.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I get different results even though the arrays have the same elements

In floating-point math, `100000000.0 + 1.0` equals `100000000.0` and not `100000001.0`, but `100000000.0 + 1024.0` does equal `100001024.0`.  Given the value `100000000.0`, the value `1.0` is too small to show up in the available bits used to represent `100000000.0`.

So when you put `100000000.0` first, all the later `+ 1.0` operations have no effect.

When you put `100000000.0` *last*, though, all the previous 1000+ `1.0 + 1.0 + ...` do add up to `1024.0`, and `1024.0` is "big enough" to make a difference given the available precision of floating point math.